# How to embed a square as a submanifold in the Euclidean plane?

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

One can give a square a differential structure, namely by transferring the smooth structure of a circle to it. But then a square in not a sub-manifold of
$\mathbb{R}^2$.

But the strong Whitney theorem implies that one can embed a square in $\mathbb{R}^2$. I would like to know how this is done.

Comment: "the smooth structure of a **circle**"

Comment: If you would like to learn something on differentiable manifolds, I'd suggest auditing or taking an undergraduate university course on differential geometry or differential topology, or else working through a good portion of a book on the lines of Guillemin and Pollack or Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds".

Comment: @PVAL, Guillemin & Pollack won't help for this question..

Comment: @TedShifrin G&P defines manifolds (albeit briskly). It proves the classification of compact 1-manifolds in the last appendix. It also defines a smooth embedding. That is plenty overkill for this question (not that I understand what "transferring the smooth structure from a circle" means in a way that makes this question non-trivial). But this question mixes a very non-trivial theorem (Whitney embedding), and then asks why a circle smoothly embeds into $\Bbb R^2$. There is a misunderstanding of the basic definitions here that either a basic course or book on either subject would fix.

Comment: I understand, @PVAL, but the *only* structure on a manifold for G&P is the one induced as it is a submanifold of $\Bbb R^n$. There is no abstract differentiable structure on a topological space. We're not worrying about the circle. We're worrying about a "funny looking" square. :) For G&P, *the* square is *not* a manifold.